# How to change instrument in Java MIDI program

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi

How can I change instruments in Midi? 
I can change the value of channel to upto 9  after that it says "Channel out of range" which is all piano. How can I change it to guitar for example

```
  public noteplay()
  throws InvalidMidiDataException,MidiUnavailableException
  {
    bpm =80;
    beatLength = 1;
    theTimeMelody = 0;
    theTimeBass =0;
    seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,3);
    trkBass = seq.createTrack();
    trkMelody = seq.createTrack();
  }
  public void melody(int volume)
    throws InvalidMidiDataException,MidiUnavailableException

  {

   int list1[] = { 56,59,60,63,56,59,60,63, 61,64,65,68,61,64,65,68,    56,59,60,63,56,59,60,63,    63,66,67,70,73,66,67,70,};

    for (int pitch : list1)
      {
    ShortMessage onMsg = new ShortMessage();
    onMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, pitch, 80);

    ShortMessage offMsg = new ShortMessage();
    offMsg.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, pitch, 90);

    trkBass.add(new MidiEvent(onMsg,theTimeBass));
    trkBass.add(new MidiEvent(offMsg,theTimeBass+beatLength));
    theTimeBass += beatLength;

      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried skipping channel 10?   It's often reserved for Drums.

Answer (score 0):

The General MIDI standard reserves the tenth channel for drums.

You can use the other fifteen channels for melodic instruments.